# Access to actuators in external object.blend file

Tags: python, logic-bricks

I'm loading scenes via `logic.getBlendFileList` and that's fine, I can access objects in it, set sensors and properties, and wire them with python modules. But I can't seem to access their animations: When I create an action actuator and select an animation (this object is an armature, appended in the scene, I can include the individual `.blend` file if needed) that this object has in the list menu, when I launch the game I get a rather laconic `Failed to load action: MyAnimation`.

On the other hand, I tried to create a "Property" actuator to toggle a boolean with a "pulse" sensor and it worked..?

Is it a limitation of `logic.getBlendFileList`, or are actions simply not available in python? Please excuse me if this is documented somewhere, in witch case can somebody please z-orient me to it?

Comment: did you load the action as well it seems to be considered separate [see this DOC](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_66_release/bge.logic.html#bge.logic.LibLoad)

Comment: Hey, this should be an answer, as it actually solved my problem; Thanks!

Comment: But [it does not work for complex actions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-to-use-playaction-on-libloaded-objects-in-bge) ;(